# error with a lift code for actual floor when > 13

Tags: java

The program is intended to set actualFloor to ﬂoor - 1 if, and only if, ﬂoor is greater than 
13. However: When the program is run, it sets actualFloor to floor - 1 for all values of floor. After studying the code for a long time and editing it, I can't seem to work out why it's doing so.
Any advice as to why it behaves like this would be very helpful thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lift
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Floor: ");
     int floor = in.nextInt();
     int actualFloor = floor;    
     if (floor > 13);
     { 
         actualFloor = floor - 1;
        }
     System.out.println("The lift will travel floor " + actualFloor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (floor > 13);
               ↑
           Remove me
```

Writing `if(floor < 13);` is like writing `if (floor > 13) { }`. So your code looks like:

```
if (floor > 13) { }
{ 
    actualFloor = floor - 1;
}
```

That's why the block is always executed.

Comment: @user3050340 Yes. I can't think of a situation where this can be useful. But.. even if you find a case where it's useful.. I prefer to use `if(somethingUseful) { }` and not putting `;`, because if I see `;` I might think it's a typo.